# iPhone - UIWebview with PDF - Searching for keyword

Tags: iphone, pdf, uiwebview

I'm showing a PDF in UIWebview. But how can I search for a particular keyword in UIWebview and high light it in PDF? Is it possible?

Comment: i couldn't find too nothing to solve that. im intersted in a solution too.